# ubicar posición de form en c#

Tags: c#

alguien podría ayudarme para ver como ubicar un windows form en la posición que yo quiera, por ejemplo hacer que al ejecutar el form aparezca en la parte inferior de la pantalla. Estoy implementando en c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo:

```
 Form form2 = new Form();
 form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
 form2.Left = 500;
 form2.Top = 500;
 form2.ShowDialog();
```

O

```
form2.Location = new Point(4, 370);   // (x,y)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, es justo lo que pensaba y buscaba ;)

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, lo primero sería saber cuales son las dimensiones de la pantalla y para ello nos basaremos en el objeto Screen del espacio System.Windows.Form:

```
int AltoPantalla = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
int AnchoPantalla = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
// Sabiendo ya las dimensiones de la pantalla puedes ubicar el Form donde quieras:
// Para el caso que lo quieras abajo sería;
MyForm.Top = AltoPantalla - MyForm.Height;
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda me dio muchas ideas